# Finding out where a function is defined

Tags: c, mobile, open-source, embedded

I'm programming in Mobile C (a mobile agent platform over C) which is open source.
I'm debugging using prints since I can't use gdb because I use a C interpreter (Embedded Ch).

The problem is there are functions I can't find out where they are defined. For example, there is the function agent_queue_RemoveIndex which is used in multiple places along the source code but I can't find out where is defined (I've looked in all define files, I've done a grep -R of the entire source code, Googled it...). When I do the grep -R I can only find calls to the function but not the definition. It seems like there is no agent_queue_RemoveIndex definition but it must because Mobile C is open-source code and the function works.

Any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: Have you considered [`cscope`](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/).  It's a curses-based interface, but it usually works for me.  On the other hand, if a case-insensitive `grep -r -i agent_queue_RemoveIndex` over the entire source doesn't find it, it must either be in system headers (which `cscope` will track down and find — at least, if given a little help about where to look), or you overlooked it in the copious output.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan's comment. If you are still unable to find out the declaration/definition of the function, then most probably, your function is part of one of the statically linked libraries. Please check if `grep -ri agent_queue_RemoveIndex .` shows any searches in binary files.

Comment: I would guess it's defined in a library you're linking to that you don't have the source for.  `nm` will list the symbols defined in an object (binary or library), that might help.  As a hack, adding your own clashing definition of the function might cause a helpful compile warning telling you where the original definition is...

Comment: Also consider macros.  It might be the case that there's some C preprocessor macro that writes out the definition of `agent_queue_RemoveIndex`.  I would personally grep for the term `RemoveIndex` instead.

Comment: A lightweight version of the above is `ctags` (creates a map of definitions and uses for `vi` and `emacs`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is defined in this [file](http://www.mobilec.org/documentation/v2.0.7/api/html/ap__queue__template_8h_source.html).

See line 64:

```
int name##_RemoveIndex(name##_p name, int index);
```

For the definition of `name##` you need to dig the linked file and the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't consider it could be a macro!